# #126 - Incorrect key file for table '.\mysql\db.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: apache-http-server, php, mysql, database, xampp

I posted [my question](https://serverfault.com/questions/733192/126-incorrect-key-file-for-table-mysql-db-myi-try-to-repair-it) on serverfault but they hold my  question by advising to post it in SuperUser

I installed Xampp and can see localhost page as well as both apache and mySQL is starting fine but when I am clicking to phpMyAdmin ==> User then I am seeing following error:

> Static analysis:
>
> 5 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position 52) Unexpected
>   closing bracket. (near ")" at position 112) Unexpected closing
>   bracket. (near ")" at position 181) Unexpected closing bracket. (near
>   ")" at position 249) Unexpected closing bracket. (near ")" at position
>   315) SQL query: Documentation
>
> (SELECT DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user` ) UNION (SELECT
>   DISTINCT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`db` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`tables_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`columns_priv` ) UNION (SELECT DISTINCT
>   `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`procs_priv` ) ORDER BY `User` ASC, `Host`
>   ASC LIMIT 0, 25
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 126 - Incorrect key file for table '.\mysql\db.MYI'; try to repair it

I restarted Xampp 2-3 times but same error. Please advise

Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 5):

Exactly the same happened to me, I tried the following query and it worked:

```
USE mysql;
CHECK TABLE db;
```

If it returns db is corrupt, then repair it using

```
REPAIR TABLE db;
CHECK TABLE db;
```

You should get status as `OK`.

Answer (score 1):

This exact same thing happened to me and I have spent the past 3-4 hours trying to fix it. After a while of researching, I found several potential solutions; such as:

- Making sure your MySQL /tmp folder had enough space, and that there is enough memory on your machine.
- Updating your database and phpMyAdmin is up to date.
- Stopping your XAMPP service, renaming the *C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\db.MYI* to *db.OLD* and starting the service again.
- Deleting the *C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql\ibdata1* and rebooting the server (this was a solution to try and combat an issue that occured after renaming the db.MYI file)
- Installing a supposed patch version of XAMPP with a custom version of phpMyAdmin (https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=72035&hilit=mysql+can%2527t+start&start=30 - view last post by Beltran)

However, none of these solutions worked for me. From what I can gather, the issue is with XAMPP changing the database service from MySQL to MariaDB and there being some compadibility issues with phpMyAdmin. Even after I installed Beltran's *fixed* version, I still had trouble creating users and other random errors would pop up. All of the solutions above have supposedly worked for others; hence me condencing and posting them here.

In the end, to fix the problems and errors; I just installed the last version of XAMPP which still had MySQL by default (**5.6.12**). The only alteration I made was updating phpMyAdmin to the latest version; which worked fine. So far I have been able access the users panel and create new users through the web interface; and there have been no problems so far. Here is a link to download the XAMPP 5.6.12 for Windows - http://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/5.6.12/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply but I used very simple way to fix it. Please read it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33465785/phpmyadmin-error-i-am-seeing-errors-in-user-accounts

Comment: Happy you found a solution! Unfortunately for me, I never had my XAMPP directory in the Program Files folder. There is a pop up in the installer that says that there are issues saving it there, so I placed it else where.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
REPAIR TABLE mysql.db;
CHECK TABLE  mysql.db;
```